# How to make JS wait for previous lines of code to finish first?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i have an issue with JS and nodeJS, and is that it runs whole code at the same time and doesnt wait for a previous function to finish its work (compared to python). How do i make it first finish its function, push the results to array and only then print to console the whole array? `await` doesnt seem to work in any kind of `for` loop

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const fetchlink = async (i) => {
    let url = `http://linktofetch`
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    const answer = await response.json()
    return answer
}
const arr = []
let pushtoarr = async (value) => {
    arr.push(value)
}
let main = async () => {
    for(let i=1;i < 10; i++){
        const answer = fetchlink(i).then((response) => {
            response.data.items.forEach(el =>{
                pushtoarr(el.name)
            }
        )
    })
    }
    console.log(arr)
}
main()
```

Comment: You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to fetch all the data.  When it is done you can continue in the `.then()` method.

Comment: Do you use `i` in `fetchLink` in your real code? Else, it's a useless argument

Comment: Why do you asynchronize a simple push to an array?

Comment: Yeah Nino i do use it in actual code. Separate function for array was because i tried to figure out how to make it work properly, but yes it is in fact useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing `foo.then(bar)`, `bar`doesn't execute immediately, instead you're just registering a callback that will execute `bar` later on, and you should instead be doing `const baz = await foo; bar(baz)`.

So, in your example, you should rewrite your code as:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const fetchlink = async (i) => {
  let url = `http://linktofetch`;
  let response = await fetch(url, { method: 'GET' });
  const answer = await response.json();
  return answer;
}


(async () => {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i=1; i<10; i++) {
    const response = await fetchLink(i);
    for (const el of response.data.items) {
      arr.push(el.name);
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
})();
```

Comment: This one works, thank you! For whatever reason when i tried to use await in a for cycle before, it wasnt working, maybe due to .then() usage

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test but it will look somehow like this

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

(async () => {
    const arr = []

    for(let i=1;i < 10; i++) {
        const response = await fetchlink(i)
        const answer = response.data.items.forEach(el => arr.push(el))
    }
    console.log(arr)
})()

async function fetchlink (i) {
    let url = `http://linktofetch`
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    return response.json()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to do an asynchronous task synchronously. There are generally two ways you can go about executing an async function and which one you use depends on what you need from the function.

## Non-Blocking

In general, an async function will return a Promise. In order to get the results of a promise you have to unwrap it like so,

```
asyncFunction(args).then((promiseResult) => { doStuff(promiseResult); });
```

The key part is that you unwrap the promise using `then` which will only trigger after the original promise has finished. This means that code execution will not wait for the promise to get unwrapped to execute the lines after. For example:

```
asyncFunction(args).then((promiseResult) => { doStuff(promiseResult); });
console.log('done');
```

In this case the log function will generally happen before the doStuff function gets called.

## Blocking

In the event that you want to block or wait for a promise to unwrap, you need to use the await keyword like so,

```
const promiseResult = await asyncFunction(args);
doStuff(promiseResult);
console.log('done');
```

In this example, no code after the await line will get executed until the asyncFunction resolves. The important thing to understand is that it only is true within the scope of code you are in. If there is a non-blocking async function being executed inside of asyncFunction, it will not wait to finish resolving that before returning to doStuff.

I will omit the actual modification to fix your code as it seems a few other people have beat me to that, however, I hope that explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use promise

example usage below

```
'use strict';
var promiseCount = 0;

function testPromise() {
    let thisPromiseCount = ++promiseCount;

    let log = document.getElementById('log');
    log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', thisPromiseCount +
        ') Started (<small>Sync code started</small>)<br/>');

    // We make a new promise: we promise a numeric count of this promise, starting from 1 (after waiting 3s)
    let p1 = new Promise(
        // The executor function is called with the ability to resolve or
        // reject the promise
       (resolve, reject) => {
            log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', thisPromiseCount +
                ') Promise started (<small>Async code started</small>)<br/>');
            // This is only an example to create asynchronism
            window.setTimeout(
                function() {
                    // We fulfill the promise !
                    resolve(thisPromiseCount);
                }, Math.random() * 2000 + 1000);
        }
    );

    // We define what to do when the promise is resolved with the then() call,
    // and what to do when the promise is rejected with the catch() call
    p1.then(
        // Log the fulfillment value
        function(val) {
            log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', val +
                ') Promise fulfilled (<small>Async code terminated</small>)<br/>');
        }).catch(
        // Log the rejection reason
       (reason) => {
            console.log('Handle rejected promise ('+reason+') here.');
        });

    log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', thisPromiseCount +
        ') Promise made (<small>Sync code terminated</small>)<br/>');
}
```

reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: OP is already using promises. How does that answers the question? The code is very complex, can you explain what does it even do?

Comment: Consider using Promise.all with array of functions instead using multiple async and await that make the whole block of code very complex.